# Good practice unit testing method that instantiate an object based on a condition at runtime

Tags: java, unit-testing

I have the following code class:

```
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Foo {

  private final Dao dao;

  public void processRequest(String requestId) { 
    if (this.isRequestNotFound(requestId)) {
      final TaskRunner runner = TaskRunner.builder().withDao(this.dao).build();
      runner.execute();
    }
  }
 
  private boolean isRequestNotFound(String requestId) {
    return this.dao.get(requestId) == null;
  }
}
```

And I'd like to make it unit-testable. I have the following two approach:

**Case 1**: Wrap `TaskRunner.builder().withDao(this.dao).build();` into another package-visible method and perform `spy` (Mokito) on class `Foo`.

```
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Foo {

  private final Dao dao;

  public void processRequest(String requestId) { 
    if (this.isRequestNotFound(requestId)) {
      final TaskRunner runner = this.createTaskRunner();
      runner.execute();
    }
  }

  @VisibleForTesting
  TaskRunner createTaskRunner() {
    return TaskRunner.builder().withDao(this.dao).build();
  }

  private boolean isRequestNotFound(String requestId) {
    return this.dao.get(requestId) == null;
  }
}
```

**pros**: I can perform unit test on `class Foo` directly by mocking `createTaskRunner()` method to return a mocked `TaskRunner` and verify if `TaskRunner`'s object has invoked `execute()`

**cons**: `createTaskRunner()` could have been a private method as it is only be used by class foo. Does making it package visible implies flaw in my design?

**Case 2**: Given that `TaskRunner` takes `Dao` as a field and it will invoke `Dao`'s API (Ex. `dao.put(someData)`) at some point in its implementation, I can in-directly verify whether `runner.execute()` is invoked by verifying if `dao.put(any())` has been invoked.

**pros**: No need to worry about creating or exposing any private method like `createTaskRunner()`

**cons**: I ended up testing `TaskRunner` along with `Foo`, which, sounds more like a scenario test rather than unit test.

I'm confused and I do not know which approach is a better practice in terms of writing maintainable and testable code. I'm aware that this puzzle could originated from the fact that I didn't separate the initialization of `TaskRunner` with my business logic (`runner.execute()`). But dependency-injecting `TaskRunner` seems to be an overkill to me as well because when `isRequestNotFound(...)` is `false`, I do not need to create `TaskRunner` object at all.

Thank you in advance for sharing your idea.

Comment: Inject a `TaskRunnerBuilderFactory`.

Comment: @tgdavies could you please share an example with me?

Answer (score 0):

```java
@Component
class TaskRunnerBuilderFactory {
  Builder create() {
    return taskRunner.builder();
  }
}
```

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
class TestFoo {
  @Mock
  TaskRunnerBuilderFactory taskRunnerBuilderFactory;
  @Mock
  Dao dao;
  @InjectMocks
  Foo foo;

  @Test
  void myTest() {
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: Just to double check: Then I should verify if `taskRunnerBuilderFactory.create()` has been invoked? Besides, I do not need to verify if the `runner.execute();` has been invoked, is that right?

Comment: Yes, you'll need to verify at least one of those, or both if you like.

Comment: Sorry for being dense, if I still want to verify `runner.execute()` (assuming this is a reasonable idea), how exactly can I obtain the `runner` from `taskRunner.builder()`?

Comment: You'd mock `taskRunnerBuilderFactory` to return a mock runner.

Comment: But `taskRunnerBuilderFactory` only has one API and it returns the Builder of the runner. `when(factory.create()).thenReturn(runner);` "cannot resolve method".